# Recortar un vector en varios vectores

Tags: r

Sea el siguiente vector:

```
x <- c(1, 2, "a", 2, 3, 4, "a", 3)
```

Necesito recortar un vector en multiples vectores contenidos en una lista, a partir de un elemente del mismo vector, en este caso a partir de `"a"`:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con R base podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 9, 2, 3, 4, 9, 3)

nro_split <- 9
lapply(split(x, cumsum(x == nro_split)), function(x) {x[x!=nro_split]})


$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 2 3 4

$`2`
[1] 3
```

En este ejemplo queremos recortar en bloques a partir de la aparición de un `9`.

- En primer lugar `cumsum(x == nro_split)` armará los grupos a partir de cada aparición de `nro_split`, es decir: `[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2`
- Aplicando luego `split()` separamos cada bloque en una lista
- Lo único que nos restaría hacer es eliminar cada `nro_split`, para eso aplicamos con `lapply` la función `function(x) {x[x!=nro_split]}`.

Answer (score 2):

la función split es lo que necesitas. Le tienes que dar un factor para que sepa cómo agrupar, por ejemplo:

```
split(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,2,1))
```

regresa una lista con 1 y 4 en la primera entrada y luego 2 y 3.

Para tu problema `cumsum(x=="a")` crea el factor que se necesita.

Luego tienes que asegurarte de eliminar las "a" para que no sean incluidas en la lista, y una vez eliminadas conviene convertir a enteros con as.integer:

```
split(as.integer(x[x!="a"]),cumsum(x=="a")[x!="a"])
```